# Soapui dropdown does not work as expected

Tags: soap, drop-down-menu, groovy, dialog, soapui

Working with Soap Responses with Soapui..

This will pull up individual questions into a dialog..  Works great..

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Question#Response");
holder.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://some.namespace.com";
def responseId = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:questionText");
ui.showInfoMessage( responseId,"Question being asked" );
```

Going to a drop-down model, things get a bit interesting.
This works, but only shows the first Question and Answer as only one item in the dropdown and shows dropdowns on each click..  I would like to show the question headers and the choices, in other words, read the xml response from the previous response from SOAP..

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Question#Response");
holder.namespaces["ns2"] = "http://some.namespace.com";
for (responseId in holder["//ns2:text"])
//ui.showInfoMessage( responseId,"Question being asked" );
ui.prompt("Question being asked", "text", [responseId])
//result = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.prompt("Question being asked", "Question", [responseId])
```

Here is the sample SOAP - Note: I have removed head/tail as I am mainly concerned about pulling the questions and response ids.

```
          <ns1:callStatus>
             <ns1:statusCode>SUCCESS</ns1:statusCode>
             <ns1:statusDescription>Questions and answers retrieved successfully</ns1:statusDescription>
          </ns1:callStatus>
          <ns1:payload xsi:type="ns2:Response" xmlns:ns2="http://some.namespace.com">
             <ns2:questions>
                <ns2:questionId>AAA</ns2:questionId>
                <ns2:text>What is the color of your car?</ns2:text>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>111</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Blue</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>222</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Green</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>333</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Black</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
             </ns2:questions>
             <ns2:questions>
                <ns2:questionId>BBB</ns2:questionId>
                <ns2:text>What is the name of your dog?</ns2:text>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>111</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Barney</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>222</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Rover</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>333</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Patches</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
             </ns2:questions>
             <ns2:questions>
                <ns2:questionId>CCC</ns2:questionId>
                <ns2:text>What if the name of your spouse?</ns2:text>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>111</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Latecia</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>222</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Mary</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
                <ns2:choices>
                   <ns2:choiceId>333</ns2:choiceId>
                   <ns2:text>Samantha</ns2:text>
                </ns2:choices>
             </ns2:questions>
          </ns1:payload>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and built this workaround:

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;

List<String> choice = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

/* Parse the XML to fill the lists in the following format.
   Something like:
     for (responseId in holder["//ns2:text"])
     {
        choice.add('${responseId.text} (${responseId.choiceId})')
        values.add( responseId.choiceId )
     }
*/
choice.add('label (value)') 
values.add('value')
/* Note: The 'value' in the choice list is optional but 
   should be used if you have duplicate labels. */

// Some example data:
choice.add('Red (#FF0000)')
values.add('#FF0000')
choice.add('Green (#00FF00)')
values.add('#FF0000')
choice.add('Blue (#0000FF)')
values.add('#FF0000')

// Ask the question
def result = ui.prompt("Question being asked", "text", choice, 'val')

// The answer
log.info result

// The position of the answer
log.info choice.indexOf(result)

// The associated value
log.info values.get( choice.indexOf(result) )
```

Hope this helps someone.